# Is the following sequence decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

${u_n} = \sup\{a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2},\ldots\}$

I guess this one is decreasing because if ${a_n}$ is an increasing sequence, ${u_n}$ is constant. If  ${a_n}$ is decreasing , then ${u_n}$ is as well decreasing.

Comment: If decreasing is meant strictly, it need not be decreasing. It is always non-increasing, since $\{a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\dotsc\} \subset \{a_n,a_{n+1},\dotsc\}$.

Comment: I take this one from the limsup $a_n$ definition. So is this strictly decreasing ?

Comment: Suppose $a_1=a_2=a_3=\dots$. Will $u_n$ be strictly decreasing, Peter?

Comment: Of course not .

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $u_n$ is non-increasing, provided they are numbers at all.  For example, if $a_n=n$, then each $u_n$ is not a real number (it can be considered $\infty$ if you use the extended reals).